# Erro no programa de criptografia c#

Tags: c#, windows, criptografia

Olá, estou tentando executar meu programa feito em c# com Aplicação Windows, porém está dando um erro de compilação que não estou conseguindo solucionar. Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar ! Grato ! ( O erro está acontecendo no método void Decodificar )

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace CriptografiaTrabalho
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = Codificar(textBox1.Text);
        }
        void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text = Decodificar(textBox2.Text);
        }

        public static string Codificar(string entrada) 
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cript = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            try
            {
                if (entrada.Trim() !="")
                {
                    string chave = "cx3f2e4ct4d2";
                    cript.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(chave));
                    cript.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                    ICryptoTransform dencrypt = cript.CreateEncryptor();
                    byte[] buff = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(entrada);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(dencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length));
                }
                else 
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            finally 
            {
                cript = null;
                md5 = null;
            }
        }

        public static string Decodificar(string entrada) 
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider decript = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            try 
            {
                if (entrada.Trim() != "")
                {
                    string chave = "cx3f2e4ct4d2";
                    decript.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(chave));
                    decript.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                    ICryptoTransform dencrypt = decript.CreateEncryptor();
                    byte[] buff = Convert.FromBase64String(entrada);

                    return Encoding.Default.GetString(dencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            finally 
            {
                decript = null;
                md5 = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro de compilação? Qual a mensagem?

Comment: Pessoal desculpe o erro na em *public static void Decodificar (string entrada)* a mensagem é (CriptografiaTrabalho.MainForm.Decodificar(string): nem todos os caminhos de código retornam um valor (CS0161)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta faltando um return no método, tem um return dentro do if mas somente ele não adianta, pois se a condição do if não for atendida, não haverá pra "onde ir".

Tenta assim:

```
 public static string Decodificar(string entrada) 
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider decript = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        try 
        {
            if (entrada.Trim() != "")
            {
                string chave = "cx3f2e4ct4d2";
                decript.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(chave));
                decript.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                ICryptoTransform dencrypt = decript.CreateEncryptor();
                byte[] buff = Convert.FromBase64String(entrada);

                return Encoding.Default.GetString(dencrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length));
            }
    return "";  
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        finally 
        {
            decript = null;
            md5 = null;
        }
    }
```

Repare que depois do if eu coloquei um retorno vazio..

Comment: Muito Obrigado Igor realmente nem reparei q não tinha o else dando um retorno. Vlw cara ! Agradeço !